# TableViewがすぐ更新されない

Tags: swift, uitableview

最初に表示される`ViewController`の`TextField`に値を入れてそれをデータベースに入れ、次にデータベースの値を`TableView`に一覧表示する`ViewController`を表示した時に、先ほど入れた値がTableViewに表示されません。一度アプリを終了してもう一度立ち上げて`TableView`の`ViewController`を表示すると値は表示されています。しかし値を入れてからすぐに反映させたいです。次のやり方を試したのですが、ダメでした。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25921623/how-to-reload-tableview-from-another-view-controller-in-swift

ちなみに`TabBarController`を使っています。
どうすればすぐにデータベースに入れた値を`TableView`に反映させることができるでしょうか？
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

最初のViewController

```
@IBAction func registerWord(sender: AnyObject) {
        if self.textField.text == "" {

        } else {

            let dbhelper = DatabaseHelper()
            dbhelper.inputWordToDatabase(self.registerWordStore, registerSpeech: self.registerSpeechStore)

            self.textField.text = ""

            showCompleteAlert()
        }
    }
```

データベースを処理するクラス

```
func inputWordToDatabase(registerWord: String, registerSpeech: String) {
        let ud = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        autoincrementId = ud.integerForKey("incrementKey")

        let word = Word()
        word.id = autoincrementId
        word.speech = registerSpeech
        word.word = registerWord

        let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
        realm.transactionWithBlock({ () -> Void in
            realm.addObject(word)
        })

        autoincrementId++

        ud.setInteger(autoincrementId, forKey: "incrementKey")
    }

    func outputWord(speech: String) -> Array<String> {
        var wordData: [String] = []
        let wordArray = Word.objectsWhere("speech CONTAINS %@", speech)

        for item in wordArray {
            if let wordStore = item as? Word {
                wordData.append(wordStore.word)
            }
        }

        return wordData
    }
```

TableViewのViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: "changeData:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

        let dbhelper = DatabaseHelper()
        nounData = dbhelper.outputWord("名詞")
        verbData = dbhelper.outputWord("動詞")
        adjectiveData = dbhelper.outputWord("形容詞")
        newWordData = dbhelper.outputWord("オリジナル")
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
            case 0:
                cell.textLabel?.text = nounData[indexPath.row]
            case 1:
                cell.textLabel?.text = verbData[indexPath.row]
            case 2:
                cell.textLabel?.text = adjectiveData[indexPath.row]
            default:
                cell.textLabel?.text = newWordData[indexPath.row]
            }

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: リンク先は、`NotificationCenter`を使っていますが、`Notification`のしかたがよくわからないので、基本を教えてもらいたいのでしょうか？それとも`Notification`を使わない別の方法を紹介してもらいたいのでしょうか？そこのところをはっきりしておかないと、回答はむずかしいでしょう。

Comment: やりたいことは、データ入力後にすぐにTableViewを更新させたいということです。なのでNotificationを使って更新がすぐにできるのであればNotificationを使いたいと思いますし、他のやり方があればそのやり方でTableViewをすぐに更新できたらいいです。なので、TableViewを更新させるやり方は問わず、TableViewをすぐに更新させるやり方が知りたいです。

Comment: 要求を並べ立てるのと、質問するのは、本質的に異なるものだと思いますが？せっかく`Notification`というキーワードを手に入れたのですから、それにしばらく頭を突っ込んでみてはいかがですか？私は`Notification`はいいアイデアだと思いますよ。

Comment: Notificationで少し調べてみたいと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Notification`の基礎について説明します。
Objective-C、Swiftは、いうまでもなくオブジェクト指向言語ですが、オブジェクト指向では、オブジェクト間の連携、外部からオブジェクトをどう制御するかが問題となります。Objective-C、Swiftでは、いくつかのしくみがそのために用意されています。Action-TargetやResponder Chain、Delegateなどがそうですが、それらとは異なった性質のNotificationが用意されています。Notification以外は、基本1対1の連携ですが、Notificationでは、ひとつのオブジェクトから発せられた「通知」を、複数のオブジェクトに送ることができるという特長を持ちます。（もちろん1対1の連携にも使えます）
アプリケーションは、ひとつの`NotificationCenter`というオブジェクトを持ちます。あるオブジェクトが、「通知」を発信すると、NotificationCenterがその通知を受け取り、複数のオブジェクトに向けて、その通知を発信するという仕事をします。
NotificationCenterは、`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()`で参照できます。
NotificationCenterに通知を伝えることを、`Post`といいます。

```
let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
notificationCenter.postNotificationName("MyNotification", object: self, userInfo: ["Item1": "Sunday"])
```

メソッド`postNotificaionName()`の第1引数は、通知の名称で、String型です。第2引数は、通知を送るオブジェクトです。通常`self`で、`nil`でもかまいません。第3引数は、通知といっしょに送る情報で、Dictionary型とします。情報がなければ、`nil`とします。このメソッドを使って、NotificationCenterに通知をPostします。

次は通知を受け取るオブジェクトの話をします。
NotificationCenterから発信する通知は、不特定多数のオブジェクトに送られるのではなく、NotificationCenterに登録したオブジェクト（`Observer`）だけに送られます。NotificationCenterの通知を受け取るには、まず`addObserver()`というメソッドを使って、NotificationCenterに登録する必要があります。

```
let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "didReceiveNotification:", name: "MyNotification", object: nil)
```

`addObserver()`の第1引数は、オブザーバになるオブジェクトで、多くのケースで`self`です。第2引数は、通知を受け取ったときに実行するメソッドを、セレクタで指定します。第3引数は、通知の名称をString型で記述します。`postNotificationName()`の引数に対応します。第4引数は、通知を発信したオブジェクトを示しますが、`nil`にすると、NotificationCenterが発信した通知すべてを受け取るようになりますから、通常`nil`にします。

通知を受け取ると、セレクタで指定したメソッドが実行されます。

```
func didReceiveNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let newItem = notification.userInfo!["Item1"] as? String {
        println("Received String = \(newItem)")
    }
}
```

引数は`NSNotification`型です。引数のプロパティ`userInfo`で、`postNotificationName()`で渡した情報を得ることができます。なお、プロパティ`userInfo`も、`Dictionary`のメンバーも、Otional型であることに、注意してください。

以下サンプルコードです。Tabベースのアプリで、`FirstViewController`にテーブルがあります。`SecondViewController`に移ると、そこに`TextField`があって、そこに文字列を入力し、リターンキーを押すと、`FirstViewController`のテーブルに、行が追加されるというプログラムです。

**FirstViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var dataArray = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dataArray.append("Sunday")
        dataArray.append("Monday")
        dataArray.append("Tuesday")
        // NotificationCenterに登録する。
        let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "didReceiveItem:", name: "AddItem", object: nil)
    }
    // 通知を受け取って実行するメソッド
    func didReceiveItem(sender: NSNotification) {
        if let newItem = sender.userInfo!["TextItem"] as? String {
            // テーブルのソースになる配列に、メンバーを追加。
            dataArray.append(newItem)
            // テーブルビューを再描画
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    // テーブルのDataSource
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = dataArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

}
```

**SecondViewVontroller.swift**

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    // テキストフィールドのDelegate
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // 通知を発信する。
        let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
        notificationCenter.postNotificationName("AddItem", object: nil, userInfo: ["TextItem": textField.text])
        // キーボードを下げる。
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

}
```

※サンプルコードは、Xcode 6.3 + Swift 1.2で記述したものです。旧バージョンでは、細部で異なる点があると思います。

Comment: 詳細な解説ありがとうございます。Notificationの仕様や使い方が理解できました。ありがとうございます。同時に、ご提示いただいたコードを参考に自分でNotificationを実装してみるとやりたかった動きを実現することができました。誠にありがとうございます。